# Corona SDK How to Save Timer Text?

Tags: timer, save

Is there a way to save the CountUp timer after finishing the scene as a text to other lua file? But im having an error with SaveTimer.lua on text=currentTime it said bad argument on newText. What will happen is after using timer.lua it will save its counUpText on my SaveTimer.lua

SaveTimer.lua

```
local time_label = display.newText({parent=uiGroup, text=currenTime, font=native.systemFontBold, fontSize=128, align="center"})
    time_label.x = 540
    time_label.y = 750
    time_label:setFillColor(0.9,0.9,0)
```

Timer.lua

```
  currentTime 
   local gameTime = 0
        function startTimer()
            clockTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000,doCountUp,gameTime)
        end



    function doCountUp()

            currentTime = countUpText.text
            currentTime = currentTime +1
            countUpText.text = currentTime
             if(currentTime == 0) then
                countUpText.text = currentTime
                startTimer()
        end
    end

         countUpText = display.newText(gameTime,259,50,native.systemFontBold,100)
         countDownText:setTextColor("#000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try it this way:

local time_label =   display.newText(""..currentTime.."", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, font=native.systemFontBold, fontSize=128)
time_label.x = 540
time_label.y = 750
time_label:setFillColor(0.9,0.9,0)

Sorry, I could not format that code to code field because I am on my smartphone.